# Force current index to be shown in QAbstractItemView even after losing focus

Tags: qt, widget, focus, qabstractitemview

I have an instance of `QAbstractItemView` say `QListView` with `selectionMode` set to `Qt::NoSelection`. When I activate the widget, I can see the current index highlighted. However, when I focus another widget, the current index of the `QListView` is no longer highlighted. I need the current index to be highlighted all the time no matter what widget has focus.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this event filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == ui->listView && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
    {
        //when view loses focus we highlight current item
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->select( ui->listView->currentIndex(), QItemSelectionModel::Select );
    }
    if (obj == ui->listView && event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn)
    {
        //when view gets focus we clear selection
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->clear();
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->select( ui->listView->currentIndex(), QItemSelectionModel::Select );
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

If you don't want to use event filter you can subclass view and reimplement `focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )` and `focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event )` and do same things.

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't do, what I want. I just selects the current index on the focus out. One problem is, that the selection looks different from the current index highlight. Second problem is, that the current index is being changed from outside of the widget and I need the widget to display the current index all the time correctly.

Comment: @tach when you change it outside use also `ui->listView->selectionModel()->clear();`
    `ui->listView->selectionModel()->select( ui->listView->model()->index(0,0), QItemSelectionModel::Select );` and all will be fine. Is color of selection is absolutely important?

Comment: Actually if the color was different it would look ugly. It isn't totally deal breaking but it is quite bad. I would actually rather use highlighting the current item differently - ie bold font alternative color.

Comment: @tach So you can set bold font with some color using QFont, something like: `ui->listView->model()->setData(ui->listView->currentIndex(),someFont,Qt::FontRole);`

Comment: Yes and I'll probably do that, if I can't figure the current index out. Thank you :)